# kibana filters show differents value if it's a metric or a histogram

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Does someone can explain me why this  query doesn't give the same result in this two differents vizualisations ?

The metric one give a good result!

[image: the good result]

[image: strange result]

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add

```
{
 "precision_threshold": 1000
 }
```